# JavaScript: Adding a nested property to an object that may not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Suppose I have a json object in which I record the number of visitors to my site, grouped by browser / version.

```
let data = {
    browsers: {
        chrome: {
           43 : 13, 
           44 : 11
        }, 
        firefox: {
           27: 9
        }
    }
}
```

To increment a particular browser, I need to check if several keys exist, and if not, create them.

```
let uap = UAParser(request.headers['user-agent']);

if (typeof uap.browser !== 'undefined') {

    if (typeof data.browsers === 'undefined') 
        data.browsers = {}

    if (typeof data.browsers[uap.browser.name] === 'undefined')
        data.browsers[uap.browser.name] = {}

    if (typeof data.browsers[uap.browser.name][uap.browser.version] === 'undefined')
        data.browsers[uap.browser.name][uap.browser.version] = 0

    data.browsers[uap.browser.name][uap.browser.version] += 1;
}
```

The deeper my data structure the crazier things get.

It feels like there must be a neater way to do this in javascript. There's *always* a neater way. Can anyone enlighten me here?

Comment: There is already an excellent library for such operations - lodash. It has [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) method which does what you need: `_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);`

Comment: Use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty() instead of typeof...

Comment: @DenisGiffeler that seems like a longer way of doing things. I'm trying to shorten my code

Comment: @alexmac I want to avoid using lodash or any other library for this - looking for neater vanilla JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shorter code should do the trick:

```
if (uap.browser) { // typeof is pretty much redundant for object properties.
    const name = uap.browsers.name; // Variables for readability.
    const version = uap.browser.version;

    // Default value if the property does not exist.
    const browsers = data.browsers = data.browsers || {}; 
    const browser = browsers[name] = browsers[name] || {};
    browser[version] = browser[version] || 0;

    // Finally, increment the value.
    browser[version]++;
}
```

Note that you were using `===` where you should've been using `=` (in `=== {}`).

Let's explain this line:

```
const browsers = data.browsers = data.browsers || {};
```

The last part: `data.browsers = data.browsers || {}` sets `data.browsers` to be itself if it exists. If it doesn't yet, it's set to be a new empty object.
Then, that whole value gets assigned to `browsers`, for ease of access.

Now, shorter code shouldn't be top priority, but in cases like this, you can make the code a lot more readable.

Comment: oops. yes, I see the `===` where it should be `=` - thanks for that

Comment: @roryok: np. I've added a little disclaimer about "shorter code". In the end, you want to go for readability, which may not necessarily mean "shorter" (the `name`/`version` are a good example there). Thanks for accepting this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can give up the if statements and do it like this:

```
uap.browser = uap.browser || {}
```

essentially it does the same as the if only much shorter

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very clean and generic solution using `Proxy()` I have a second solution which is standard ECMAscript 5 if you don't need it so cleanly or need it less browser dependant.

```
var handler = {
    get: function (target, property) {
        if (property !== "toJSON" && target[property] === undefined) {
            target[property] = new Proxy ({}, handler);
        }
        return target[property];
    }
}
var jsonProxy = new Proxy ({}, handler);

jsonProxy.non.existing.property = 5;
jsonProxy.another.property.that.doesnt.exist = 2;
jsonProxy["you"]["can"]["also"]["use"]["strings"] = 20;

console.log (JSON.stringify (jsonProxy));
```

You can do the same thing with classes but with a more verbose syntax:

```
var DynamicJSON = function () {};
DynamicJSON.prototype.get = function (property) {
    if (this[property] === undefined) {
        this[property] = new DynamicJSON ();
    }
    return this[property];
};
DynamicJSON.prototype.set = function (property, value) {
    this[property] = value;
};

var jsonClass = new DynamicJSON ();
jsonClass.get("non").get("existing").set("property", 5);
jsonClass.get("you").get("have").get("to").get("use").set("strings", 20);

console.log (JSON.stringify (jsonClass));
```